# Pointer to Pointer to derived class calling pure virtual function

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, virtual-functions

I am getting an error when trying to call a derived class method via a base class pointer to a base class pointer which points to the derived class. Specifically, the pure virtual function is being called instead of the implemented function in the derived class.

I won't post all the code here but this is basically what I'm doing:

```
class A
{
    protected:
        int length;


    public:
        A();
        A(int theLength);
        virtual ~A();
        virtual void printLength() = 0;
}
```

Base class .cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

A::A() : length(0)
{
}

A::A(int theLength):length(theLength)
{
}

A::~A()
{
}
```

Derived Class

```
class B : public A
{    
    public:
        B();
        B(int theLength);
        virtual ~B();
        void printLength(); // EDITED TYPO HERE
}
```

Derived class .cpp:

```
#include "B.h"

B::B() : A()
{
}

B::B(int theLength): A(theLength)
{
}

B::~B() 
{
}

void B::printLength() {
    std::cout << "The length is: " << length; 
}
```

Then I'm calling it like this:

```
Class C {
   protected:
       A** aPtr
   public:
       C();
       C(A** theAPtr);
       ~C();
       void printALength();

}

#include "C.h"
C::C() : aPtr(NULL) {}
C::C(A** theAPtr): aPtr(theAPtr) {}
C::~C() {}

void printALength() {
    (*aPtr)->printLength(); 
}

int main() {
    A* ptr = new B(); 
    A** ptr2 = &ptr; 
    C c(ptr2);
    c.printALength();
 }
```

However, instead of calling the derived class method printLength() its called the base class one , which is a pure virtual function hence the error.

Can anyone see where I may have gone wrong?

EDIT: Changed C() constructor as per comments

Comment: `aPtr(new A*)` What is the point of this, and how will you delete it? Why not set it to NULL

Comment: Yep that makes more sense.. thanks

Comment: No problem detected on MS VC 2013. I recompiled your source.

Comment: it looks fine to me but its throwing an error in OSX terminal. I think its the lvm(?) compilier